# ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am just learning Rails. I had encountered a routing error, though I think I have specified the correct rules in the routing.rb. I have attached the code. Please help

**routes.rb**

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

**Controller**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def sign_in
    @name = params[:visitor_name]
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<html> 
<head><title>Hello <%=h @name %></title></head>
<body> 
<%=h @name %>
<% form_tag :action => 'sign_in' do %>
<p>Enter your name:
<%= text_field_tag 'visitor_name', @name %></p>
<%= submit_tag 'Sign in' %>
<% end %>
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `form_tag` needs to specify the controller as well as the action. So:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => 'entries', :action => 'sign_in' do %>
```

Note that in Rails' terms, this is a very old-fashioned way of doing things and I'd recommend that you learn about RESTful routes within the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide.

Comment: Hi. I added the controller name but still it is not working :(

Comment: What is your view template file called and whereabouts is it?

Comment: Hi John...It worked :) Thanks for your suggestion about RESTful routes :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include follwing in your routes.rb

```
map.resources :entries, :collection=>{:sign_in=>:post}
```

Restart your server

```
<% form_tag :controller=>'entries' , :action => 'sign_in' do %>
```

if your view in entries folder only then you need not to specify controller name it will by default take it. just write

```
<% form_tag :action => 'sign_in' do %>
```

Comment: He doesn't _have_ to include that at all. It's clear from his routes.rb file that he's not using RESTful routing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It is still not working. I added map.resources to the routing.rb and it is the only view in my entries folder.